# SELECT INTO Dynamic table name based on records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of data that I need to divide into multiple tables based on a particular field value.

for example:

```
select name, date, state, country into dbo.[dynamicTable] from myDB
```

where `[dynamicTable]` is based on the country value in my query.

so I'd have `dbo.Spain`, `dbo.Australia` etc as tables after running the query.

is this possible, or do I have to do it the manual way.

Manual way being

`select 
  name,
  date, 
  state
into dbo.Spain
from myDB
where country = 'Spain'`

This would then be repeated for all the different countries, i.e Australia, China

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have got so far to clarify?

Comment: Don't have anything, I'm just wondering if I can do this without having to specify the table name and put in a where condition for each table that's to be created

Comment: Everyone will tell you this is bad design. Every day I see people in a bad place because they have to deal with systems that do things like this. Don't do it.

Comment: Agree with @ElecticLlama - it is highly likely that doing this is a bad design choice.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with you, but in this particular scenario it's actually quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic SQL for that kind of job:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N''

select @sql = @sql + N'select name, date, state into dbo.' 
        + quotename(country)  
        + N' from myDB where Country=''' 
        + country + N'''; '
    from myDB

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: How does that work with multiple values for @tableName?

Comment: @Matt Multiple values in what way? Can you update your question?

Comment: Updated it with what the manual method would be.  Need to automate the population of table name and where parameter

Comment: So where do you take your values from? A separate query like `select name from countries`?

Comment: Nope, they're part of the original query.  I have tableA, and want to split it into a few dozen smaller tables, where table names are tableA.country